# iOS Swift: Loading a XIB file containing a UICollectionView causing nil error?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I created a `UICollectionView` in an .xib file like so:

[image]

Based on this post: [Can´t add items to UICollectionView inside UIView xib](http://Can%C2%B4t%20add%20items%20to%20UICollectionView%20inside%20UIView%20xib)

I understand that you cannot directly add a `UICollectionViewCell` within a `UICollectionView` that is contained in a .xib, but instead have to create another .xib with only the `UICollectionViewCell`, which is what I did:

[image]

I create a `GridViewCell` class and add it as the Custom Class for the `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
class GridViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var clothingImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }
}
```

I also created a `GridViewGallery` class and associated with my `UICollectionView` .xib file:

```
extension GridViewGallery: UICollectionViewDelegate
{

}

extension GridViewGallery: UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return clothingImages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GridViewCell", for: indexPath) as! GridViewCell

        cell.clothingImageView.image = clothingImages[indexPath.row].image

        return cell
    }
}

class GridViewGallery: UIView
{
    @IBOutlet var gridLayoutCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var clothingImages = [INSPhotoViewable]()

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let gridViewCell = UINib(nibName: "GridViewCell", bundle: nil)

        gridLayoutCollectionView.register(gridViewCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "GridViewCell")
    }


    func storeGridViewImages(photos: [INSPhotoViewable])
    {
        clothingImages = photos

        gridLayoutCollectionView.dataSource = self
        gridLayoutCollectionView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

However, I get a `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error when I tried to load the XIB file to a `UIView` in another class:

```
@IBAction func gridViewLayout(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    if let gridView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("GridViewGallery", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? GridViewGallery
    {
        print("GRID VIEW FOUND")

        self.addSubview(gridView)
    }
}
```

The `GridViewGallery` File Owner's Custom Class is empty, as I set the Custom Class on the `UIView` property instead as seen in the first screenshot:

[image]

However, if I instead set the File Owner's Custom Class to `GridViewGallery` and leave the Custom Class as blank from the `UIView` itself, then I get a crash with error `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key gridLayoutCollectionView`.

I'm not sure I understand what is causing this, and which way I should be setting the Custom Class.

Can someone assist me?

Thanks.

Comment: You've connected outlets to a UIView object, that's why you see the crash. Remove all outlets from your View and connect them to files owner.

Comment: @StasVolskiy I have tried doing that as explained near the bottom, but as mentioned I get a `key value coding-compliant` error..unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: a key value coding-compliant error occurs because you've set an outlets to a UIView. UIView doesn't have a property "gridLayoutCollectionView" so that's the crash. Remove all outlets in your XIB (select each element, go to outlets tab and remove all). Then, set a files owner class GridViewGallery and view class leave as UIView. Connect all the outlets to files owner and run

Comment: I have removed all outlets in my XIB file, and removed `GridViewGallery` from the View's Custom class and have set `GridViewGallery` as the Custom Class of the File's Owner. Within Outlet's tab of the File Owner, I see `gridLayoutCollectionView`, so I ctrl+drag that outlet to the `@IBOutlet var gridLayoutCollectionView: UICollectionView!` and connect it, but I still receive the `key value coding-compliant` error...When I go to the View's Outlet tab, I see no IBOutlets connected....is that not how you suggest to do it?

Comment: tap on your collectionView, go to outlets tab and check how many referenced outlets it has :)

Comment: Selecting the `UICollectionView` under the `UIView`, I see `Referencing Outlets` with `gridLayoutCollectionView` attached to File's Owner, and nothing else

Comment: One more thing here Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("GridViewGallery", owner: self, options: nil)?.first. Make owner (self) is a UIView in your case? set an owner to nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153002/discussion-between-pangu-and-stas-volskiy).